# Gitlab CI saving output files

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

In my Gitlab CI pipeline, I am downloading a dataset from web and need to store the data inside the machine where my Gitlab runner runs. Before that one I tried to use Gitlab Artifacts but since the dataset quite big (20gb), storing outputs inside Gitlab server was not a suitable option.

In my runner I defined volumes but It is not saving the files inside the directory in my server.

```
[[runners]]
  .....
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "pytorch/pytorch:2.0.1-cuda11.7-cudnn8-devel"
    runtime = "nvidia"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock", "/usr/bin/nvidia-smi:/usr/bin/nvidia-smi", "/cache", "/full_path/dist/pedestrian:/home/ci-artifacts"]
    shm_size = 300000
    network_mtu = 0
```

And the gitlab ci file as follows:

```
build:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - runner
  script:
    - pwd  
    - poetry build -v
    - mkdir -p dist/pedestrian/
    ......
    - cp -r /full_path/dist/pedestrian /home/ci-artifacts
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Looks fine, so the pipelien suceeds? What you can do, is add `sleep 3600` to the job, then login to the server, find `docker ps` the docker container it is runing in and `docker inspect` it to find if it uses proper volumes.

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you sure you have only one runner with the tag `runner` and this runner triggers the job?
2. Make sure you have correct linux permissions for folder `/full_path/dist/pedestrian` or at least play with `chmod 0777 /full_path/dist/pedestrian` to see what will happen`.
3. Add `CI_DEBUG_TRACE: true` to see more details about where it copies.
4. Add `sleep 9000` after it is copied, then SSH to the runner's node to see if files or folders exist.